# "FileNotFoundError" During Handling of "FileExistsError"

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to create a directory in a class constructor but there is a possibility of there is a directory with the same name as I want to create. So I'm trying the following approach.

```
class SubVideoExtractor:
    def __init__(self, out_name=str()):
        self.out_abs = os.getcwd() + "/output/" + out_name
        try:
            os.mkdir(self.out_abs)
        except FileExistsError:
            subprocess.Popen(f"rm -rf {self.out_abs}").wait()
            os.mkdir(self.out_abs)
```

But when directory already exist, I got `FileNotFound` error during handling of `FileExistsError`.

How error looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lapestand/DEV/projects/SubVideoExtractor/SubVideoExtractor.py", line 22, in __init__
    os.mkdir(self.out_abs)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/home/lapestand/DEV/projects/SubVideoExtractor/output/16035609841603553594'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 95, in <module>
    extractor = SubVideoExtractor(length=VIDEO_LENGTH, _format=VIDEO_FORMAT,
  File "/home/lapestand/DEV/projects/SubVideoExtractor/SubVideoExtractor.py", line 24, in __init__
    subprocess.Popen(f"rm -rf {self.out_abs}").wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rm -rf /home/lapestand/DEV/projects/SubVideoExtractor/output/16035609841603553594'
```

Why this is happening and how to solve?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are other ways to go about what you're trying to do without catching an exception. That said, after glancing at the docs, it appears you should be passing in an array with your command to `Popen` as follows:

```
subprocess.Popen(["rm", "-rf", f"{self.out_abs}"]).wait()
```

Comment: this isn't very pythonic

Answer (score 0):

You may want to continue even if the folder exists:

```py
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
```

But you may prefer to really delete the folder before recreate it:

```py
shutil.rmtree(path)
```